# Associate Array of Keys with Array of Values Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have one array of keys that I want to associate with all of the data returned from the API:

```
        const arr = [
          'cat',
          'dog',
          'horse',
        ]

const data_from_api = [
            ["cat_1",
            "dog_1",
            "horse_1"],

            ["cat_2",
            "dog_2",
            "horse_2"],
]
```

I want to create objects with the data that the keys area the values of this array and the values are the data that come from the API. How could I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should the mapping be done by array-index? Does `cat_1` belong to `cat`, because it has index `[0]` in your and the api's arrays?

Answer (score -1):

You could iterate over the api-data like this:

```js
const arr = 
  ['cat',  'dog',  'horse',]
const data_from_api = [
  ['cat_1','dog_1','horse_1'],
  ['cat_2','dog_2','horse_2'],
]

const result = {}
data_from_api.forEach((api, i) =>

  // find array item (or create one, if not yet existant)
  (result[arr[i]] || (result[arr[i]] = []))

  // add current item
  .push(data_from_api[i])
)
console.log(result);
```

The result would be:

```
{
  cat: [["cat_1", "dog_1", "horse_1"]],
  dog: [["cat_2", "dog_2", "horse_2"]]
}
```